# Suppose $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is differentiable function. Then which of the following statements are necessarily true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

1. If $f'(x) \leq r <1$ for all x $\in \mathbb R$, then $f$ has atleast one fixed point.
2. If $f$ has a unique fixed point, then $f'(x) \leq r <1$ for all x $\in \mathbb R$.
3. If $f$ has unique fixed point , then $f'(x) \geq r > -1$ for all x $\in \mathbb R$.
4. If $f' \leq r < 1$ for all x $\in \mathbb R$, then $f$ has a unique fixed point.

If we take $f(x) = x^2 + \frac{1}{4}  $, then (2) and (3) are not true, I think (1) and (4) are true, please help me to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ has two fixed points $x =  0,1$. But you can use $f(x) = x^2 + \tfrac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Jimmy : Sorry Sir, I am ediiting

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Suppose $f'(x) \le r < 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $g(x) = f(x) - x$.

Since $g'(x) = f'(x) - 1 \le r-1 < 0$, we have that $g(x)$ is strictly decreasing. (and decreasing at least as fast as $(r-1)x$)

So, how many zeros does $g(x)$ have?

Comment: Was typing this very trick up, but you were too quick! Nice work, +1

Comment: @ Jimmy : How can you say that g has a unique zero.

Comment: @ Struggler: Can $g$ have two distinct zeros? Can $g$ have no zeros? Try to explain why two cases are impossible. You'll need to use the fact that $g'(x) \le r-1 <0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as well as the fact that $g(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Jimmy @ : I am agree your point that g has atmost one zero,because g  is a decreasing function

Comment: If $\exists$ a and b such that $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ are opposite sign , then $\exists$ c $\in $ (a,b) s.t $g(c) = 0$. If $g(x) > 0 $, then $f(x) > x$,then $f'(x) >1$,which is a contradiction. If $g(x) < 0$  and $f'(x) \leq r$, then $|f(x) -f(y) | < r |x -y|$ by theorem of walter rudin 9.19, so by contraction mapping theorem,$f$ has a fixed point. Am I right.